# Extract (random) image with no useful src= from web page

Tags: html, ruby, capybara

First I'd like to know how this can be achieved in general, and then maybe someone knows how to accomplish this using Capybara.

Example: `<img src="http://example.com/getrandomimage">`
Thing is, `src` points to a script which returns random image, not to the image itself.
Page is loaded, script is run, image is displayed. I can easily get the `src` value, but if I access the link to download the image, the script runs again and returns a totally different picture. And I need the one that's already on the page.

Comment: You need to show code you've written in an attempt to solve this. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: What’s example input HTML? What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: Please see the edit, hope it's clear now

Comment: @the Tin Man, not sure which code to show, I want to figure out the approach before writing some.

Answer (score 0):

I think the process would be very similar using JS or Capybara.  I'd break it down into two steps:

1. Write a selector that will find the `<img>` tag.  In JS that might look like:

   ```
   myImg = document.getElementByTagName("img")
   ```
2. Call `.src` on the returned node:

   ```
   result = myImg.src
   ```

I believe Capybara is limited to XPath and CSS selectors.  Therefore, depending on the page you are trying to scrape, you'll have to identify some sort of pattern in the HTML tags or the CSS attributes to find the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Writing a selector is no problem. But won't .src just return the `src`'s value as in my example?

Comment: I must not understand the question.